# How to reduce APK size in HERE Maps Android SDK

Tags: android, kotlin, sdk, here-api

I have used Premium Android SDK of **HERE Maps API** and implemented demo app. But my application size is **65 MB**.

Also I have enabled `shrinkResources` in app `build.gradle` file as follows, but this didn't work for me.

```
 android {
    // Other settings

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

So, my question is how can we reduce APK size used in Android SDK on HERE Maps API.

Comment: Share your gradle dependency

Comment: This is an aar file , this  provided by Here Maps Premium  SDK.     **implementation(name: 'HERE-sdk', ext: 'aar')**

Comment: Use the APK Analyzer in Android Studio to see where your space is going.

Comment: @CommonsWare Here-sdk aar size is 62MB. all space gone by in libs folder

Comment: If `libs` contains several CPU architectures, you might consider using [APK splits](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits) to have different APKs per CPU architecture.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have used splits {
    abi {
        include 'armeabi', 'mips', 'mips64'
 
    }
}

but facing same issue

Comment: There are some fonts you can try deleting (https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/dev_guide/topics/size-management.html) however the Premium sdk is about 50-60 Mb in the end and you might not be able to bring it down further. If a light weight aplpication is required you might consider using the Starter SDK (with limited features ofcourse)

Answer (score 1):

Summary: There are some fonts you can try deleting (developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/dev_guide/…) however the Premium SDK is about 50-60 Mb in the end and you might not be able to bring it down further. 
If a light weight application is required you might consider using the HERE SDK Lite (with limited features of course)

Comment: How to remove that fonts from the integration?

Comment: @softwaresupply App level gradle > android{ packagingOptions {
        exclude '/lib/armeabi-v7a/libNanumGothicFontPkg.so'
        exclude '/lib/armeabi-v7a/libLohitIndicFontPkg.so'
        exclude '/lib/armeabi-v7a/libChineseFontPkg.so'
    }}